# Error configuring 2 network interfaces on the same server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, linux-networking

I'm setting up a server with 2 network interfaces each one with it's IP address.
I have 2 different programs listening on port 8080 (each one on each IP address) and I'm using iptables to redirect traffic from port 80 to 8080.

The problem is that I'm unable to actually connect to the IP address of eth1 from another computer. If I try it from the same server it works as expected but from other computer the connection times out. I'm guessing the iptables is sending all the traffic to eth0 and because there's no program listening to that IP on that interface so the connection times out but I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Here is the output of my network config:

```
→  sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https redir ports 8443
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8080

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         


→  ip route               
default via 172.31.16.1 dev eth0 
172.31.16.0/20 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.21.84 
172.31.16.0/20 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.26.28 


→  route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth1


→  ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:bb:c3:cc:8b:47  
          inet addr:172.31.21.84  Bcast:172.31.31.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::bb:c3ff:fecc:8b47/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:6300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1095572 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1064691 (1.0 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:71:e7:b4:bc:52  
          inet addr:172.31.26.28  Bcast:172.31.31.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::71:e7ff:feb4:bc52/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11236 (11.2 KB)  TX bytes:1422 (1.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:63 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:63 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:43236 (43.2 KB)  TX bytes:43236 (43.2 KB)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create individual rules for the 2 NICs. I'd try something like this:

```
$ sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
$ sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

$ sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
$ sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

Comment: This is probably a good idea, but after the change I'm seeing the same behavior.

Comment: I'd run a `tcpdump -nnvXSs0 -i eth0 port 80` and confirm that traffic is coming in properly. Do the same for the `eth1`. I believe you also need to add INPUT rules. Something like this - `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: Ran it, and traffic is coming in for both interfaces

Answer (score 1):

I had to add individual rules for iptables as slm said and also I had to use 2 lookup tables for the rules for each interface, like this:

```
sudo ip route add default via 172.31.16.1 dev eth0 tab 1
sudo ip route add default via 172.31.16.1 dev eth1 tab 2

sudo ip rule add from 172.31.21.84/32 tab 1
sudo ip rule add from 172.31.26.28/32 tab 2
```